# ionic 3 ios can't find sourcemaps and banner not clickable

Tags: cordova-admob

Anyone's facing the same issues?

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/plugins/cordova-plugin-admob-free/www/admob.js.map

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/polyfills/promise-7.0.4.min.js.map

Banner shows but not clickable.
Interstitial works perfectly.

$ ionic info
✔ Gathering environment info - done!

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
Cordova Platforms : android 6.3.0, ios 4.5.5
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4, (and 18 other plugins)

System:

ios-deploy : 1.9.2
ios-sim : 5.0.6
NodeJS : v8.11.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm : 6.4.1
OS : macOS Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b

Answer (score 0):

Plugin conflicts with googlemaps in my case. See the workaround here.

https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free/issues/283